# Uploadify not uploading all pictures?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, file-upload, uploadify

You can see my live example here: http://friendsconnect.org/scrapbooks/live_example.php. You may see that some pictures, for whatever reason, arn't being uploaded. Why is this? Does uploadify have certain restrictions, and if so how do I lift them? I have check the documentation here: http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/ but I haven't found anything relating to the problem. You can see below, some pictures are "broken" and turn out to not be even uploaded.

[image: Uploadify Pictures not uploading.]

I'm also using a timthumbs script to reduce the file size, but that's not the problem as it says "File not found" and so the file doesn't exist, which leads back to the problem residing with uploadify. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Images are JPG files, but can range. Size varies but mainly from 1-2MB.

Comment: Can we have some informations about the missing images(type,size,name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be an issue with your PHP script. I've just uploaded a picture, and your web page is giving me the following details:

```
URL: http://www.friendsconnect.org/jquery_custom/create_user_image.php?src=/scrapbooks/uploads/image.png&h=80&w=100
Content: 
<pre>no mime type specified<br />Query String : src=/scrapbooks/uploads/image.png&amp;h=80&amp;w=100<br />TimThumb version : 1.26</pre>
```

Now, you're putting that `text/html` content into a `img` tag, which obviously won't work, and so we get this broken image thing.

NB: This only occurs on some of my uploaded images, most work fine.